# absolute imports in python 3 and django (library and app have the same name)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a django project where one of the apps has the same name that a python library (foo) that I am using. When I import the library from the django's settings.py file (from foo import bar), instead of importing the library, it imports the local django application. I understand that Python 3 uses absolute imports by default, thus it should try to load first the library before the local django app. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Which one are you trying to load? the local django one? `from .foo`

Comment: no, the global library one (from foo import bar) but instead is loading the local one...

Comment: that solves the problem but creates others in my case. I was trying to figure out why it is loading the app instead of the library first as absolute imports implies that it will try to load a library first

Comment: Please show your project layout.